# Mule API Kit not available on 3.6.1 CE server?

Tags: maven, mule

I have a Mule project which makes use of a REST API Via the Mule Apikit.
When I run the project as a 'Mule Application' from eclipse there are no issues.

when I run the project as a 'Mule Application with Maven'  the application builds but on startup of the mule server  i see errors relating to resolution of the apikit schema and later namespace within my flows. ( I see the same thing when I load the application to a standalone Mule server.

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/apikit/current/mule-apikit.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
```

I have two entries in my .pom file related to apikit.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-module-apikit</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mule.tools.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>mule-app-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${mule.tools.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <copyToAppsDirectory>true</copyToAppsDirectory>

                <inclusions>
                        <inclusion>
                            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mule-module-apikit</artifactId>
                        </inclusion>
                    </inclusions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: Is `mule-module-apikit-1.6.1.jar` correctly packaged in the application zip, under `/lib`?

Comment: No, and I've tried explicitly setting the scope of the dependancy (neither compile nor runtime are including it). I can also confirm it's in my local .m2 directory, so it's not having an issue finding the jar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the Mule Maven plugin excludes all Mule dependencies, regardless of their scopes.

You need to forcefully include the APIkit dependency with:

```
<configuration>
    <inclusions>
        <inclusion>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-apikit</artifactId>
        </inclusion>
    </inclusions>
</configuration>
```

Reference: https://github.com/mulesoft/maven-mule-plugin/tree/maven-mule-plugin-1.9#managing-dependencies

Comment: In my case I do have that inclusion (see the second code block with .pom details in my question)  but the apikit jar remains uncopied.   I've added an answer  to this question outlining what has solved it for me in the short term.

Comment: Let's try something else: try adding `<excludeMuleDependencies>false</excludeMuleDependencies>` to the `configuration` element.

Comment: Just tested that, same result -  the resulting zip contains no lib directory.

Comment: wait, I stand corrected.  I've had that configuration on the wrong mule plugin ( you can see above I have it on mule-app-maven-plugin,  but it should have been on maven-mule-plugin).  That's working for me now.

Answer (score 1):

This plugin seems to be the culprit:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mule.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-mule-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
        </plugin>
```

When it is present the lib directory in the resulting zip is not populated, when it is removed the apikit (and other libraries) are present.

There are side effects to this however,  This plugin seems to allow recognition of flow xml files in subfolders of the /app/ directory (which my project was using).   Also adding/removing the dependancy seems to impact on the eclipse project ( I've seen it remove all of my src folders and replace them with a single /src/).

Comment: fwiw, I'd like to keep the subfolder structure (and i suspect not having the maven-mule-plugin isn't really a long term solution) -

Comment: Did you ever find a better solution to this issue?

Comment: Afraid not, that's not to say there isn't a solution, I just haven't  been working in Mule for a while so haven't had the motivation to investigate any further.

Comment: ...doh, looking at the accepted answer and comments therein looks like I did get this solved (It was a year ago in fairness)